# Accounts creation/login to view personal data

Tags: php, web, content-management-system

how is it possible to make something like this:

Admin Creates accounts with specific username and password
then from the website the user logs in to his account and views personal account data the admin uploaded to his account.

For instance there is a client who has bought something.Then he logs in to his site account and views what he bought last week (in fact browsing specific server data)

How can that be done?With a simple script?A cms or what?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic so far?

Comment: Something like this is a little too complex to answer. There are so many variables that come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is in google :)
Really try to search a little in google something like "user management with php" and probably you can find a huge quantity of answer.

Btw i think that to do a basic user management with php you need:

1. Design a database that handle user and if needed basket, and whatever you want (news, etc.).
2. Then the basic information you need in your database for usera management are:
   Username, email, password (be sure that the password is crypted for example with md5) and the user role (admin, editor, etc).
3. You need to specify the user roles (i think you can use a table for it, or a file, it is only up to you to decide how roles are handled).
4. For track purchase of the user you must create a relation between purchases and user_id So for example you can have a table called orders where you have minimum these files item_id order_id user_id so the user can have in its dashboard a complete tracking of its history.
5. Then how to manage user sessions? You can use COOKIEs so if the user login succesfully you set a cookie into user browser, and then check if the cookie exist you show for example some information, if the cookie doesn't exist you show other informations.

These are the basic steps to manage users (probably many information are missing). But this is good if you want to learn something, but if you want something strong and probably more secure you can think to use a CMS and maybe only create some customization of it if needed.

Comment: great post,thanks for that valuable info :) It looks like a cms is a good option,which one do you suggest to serve my needs?(create users by admin,login and let them see a unique content for each user) :)

Comment: This question depends on your needs, really. I can suggest to check several of them, look if they have modules for your need, and then choose. I worked fine with joomla and wordpress (but the latest is good for blogging). Actually i'm trying Drupal, and i find that it is very powerful and highly customizable. It is only a little bit difficult to implement some custom objects (but maybe you don't need  it). If you liked my answer please +1 at it (or consider to accept it) :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with script, or cms. I think script is more suitable than cms - which would be overkill, and you would have to spend more time trying to get the cms out of the way than actually doing what you want.

The best option in my mind however is a framework. Seeing as how you have tagged your question php, I am going to recommend CakePHP. This will allow you to solve your problem quickly, by making a simple app based on user accounts, and also to be able to leverage existing codebase (including plugins like ACL for example). This approach will allow you to maintain structure, and develop/maintain your app more easily in the future.

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer,i tagged php because i thought that language would be the most appropriate,on the other hand i have no skill with php :( any quidelines?Thanks again

Comment: You could use many other languages with similar frameworks. Backbone.js might be an nice way to go, as javascript is a pretty easy introduction to programming if you don't have much experience. Otherwise, Ruby on Rails, or Django (or web2py) for Python. The important thing in my mind, is to use a framework (probably based on MVC) so that you can benefit from structured code, and plugin existing code rather than baking your own.

Comment: thanks,i have big javascript experience but i was talking about php thanks for your answer anyway :)))) oh and i already marked onother answer as the most suitable ;)

Comment: Just for curiosity - why would you not use Backbone.js if you are already very familiar with javascript?

Comment: i am aware of the backbone library but in that case i think its better to use drupal instead :)